# How to make service checks start exactly at 0th second of every minute in Nagios?

Tags: nagios

I'm working on monitoring applications that I want to run as Nagios plugins. I am quite unhappy with the way Nagios scheduler works, because I need my apps to be executed every minute at 0th second, just like the Linux' Cron daemon does it. Unfortunately for me Nagios is not very strict with keeping time intervals and it has a number of options in the main config file to do 'smart' scheduling to avoid load peaks either on the monitoring host or monitored host(s). I set service_inter_check_delay_method to n which at least made the checks more regular, but they are still not being scheduled at the 0th second of a minute. 
I'm thinking about employing Cron and run passive checks as a workaround, but I don't quite like it as my priority is to solve this problem by changing Nagios settings. If someone has any good suggestions please advise.

Regards,
MK

Answer (score 0):

If you set service_inter_check_delay_method=n and you start nagios with at command or cron your checks with interval 1min must run each 1 minute. If no maybe you have another lattencies problems or you need to review your interval_length setting.

I hope i help to you a few. Another ideas i can offer you is, develop a custom python script to control the time execution. The python script you can get time and use time.delay(microseconds) to delay your script execution until the first second of each minute. You will need to use timedelta functions in python.